# regex find exact word/sentences match

Tags: c#, regex

I have a linq list with `"impportent words"` which holds sentences and single words.

I need to find if there is any word or sentences from importent_words which is found in  `"sentence_to_search_for_importent_word"`

At last the result should end up in a array or something.

here is what i done until know..

```
List<string> importent_words = new List<string>() {"age", "what is", ".", "pages"}

string sentence_to_search_for_importent_words = "what is your age.";
```

I need to find the `importent_words` in a sentence and get all the matches outputted to a list

I try this but it does not really do the job

```
var pattern = new Regex(@"\w+");
var qa = pattern.Split(first_sentence.ToLower()).Where(w => importent_words.Contains(w));
```

It have to return "age"  not "ages" also it should find "what is" not only "what"

With `\w` it seems to find age but it only output `"this"` instead of `"this is"`

It seems like the problem is that "this is" is more than one word.

Comment: Are you looking for `importent_words.Where(x => sentence.Contains(x))`? why regex?

Comment: I would agree, using a regex introduces a second problem, you are not looking for a pattern so a basic check will be ten times better

Comment: i just thought regex was fast, any solution witch is just as good is great too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you're looking for is the important words that appear in your sentence then you can just use

```
importent_words.Where(x => sentence.Contains(x))
```

If this needs to be case insensitive then you can find a replacement for the `Contains(x)` from the answers to [Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring) (or use `sentence.ToLower()` as you show in your current regex attempt)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you'd like an extendable regex solution. The matches need to be escaped for the regex pattern. You could utilize Regex.Escape() for this.

```
List<string> importent_words = new List<string>() { "age", "what is", @"\.", "ages", "bob" };
string sentence_to_search_for_importent_words = "what is your age. Frank";
string regexString = string.Join("|" , importent_words.ToArray());
Regex wordRegex = new Regex(regexString);

string[] result = wordRegex.Matches(sentence_to_search_for_importent_words)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: what does the @"\."   do

Comment: @ before a string in C# escapes the characters so \ will be written as-is. Regex needs to be given \. so that the period is considered as a period but not 'any single character'.

Comment: thx alot. made great sence. had never understood the term exscape before in regex.